# Stanford NLP : Corpus of coreference resolution

Tags: stanford-nlp, corpus

I was simply wondering on which corpus was trained the english statistical coreference resolution system of Stanford NLP. Would it be effective if used on novels ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coreference model is trained on the CoNLL 2012 coreference data set, which is related to the OntoNotes 5.0 data set.

Here is the link to the data:

http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html